Updating Stack Settings for Azure Functions using an ARM Template or Bicep file
I am updating an Azure Functions project from .NET 7 to .NET 8 and it is not picking up any of the HTTP Handlers in the Azure Portal when it previously would when targeting .NET 7.
I added the environment variable FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME with the value dotnet-isolated as mentioned in the answer on this other question states and this makes the ability to change the stack settings through the Azure Portal possible but I want to be able to set this in configuration, either through an ARM template or a Bicep file

check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-infrastructure-as-code?tabs=json%2Cwindows%2Cdevops&pivots=consumption-plan#create-the-function-app

It has worked by setting netFrameworkVersion to v8.0, why was this not the case for .NET 7 and not included in the upgrade documentation for moving to .NET 8?

Have you tried the same template for .Net 7?

Yes I had but your link has helped me achieve it with .NET 8

Do you have any further issue?

No I don't, could you write it as an answer so I can mark this question as answered?

To create an isolated function along with the configuration settings using Arm template, you can either refer to this MS Doc or check the code below-
"resources": [
  {
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
    "apiVersion": "2022-03-01",
    "name": "[parameters('functionAppName')]",
    "location": "[parameters('location')]",
    "kind": "functionapp",
    "dependsOn": [
      "[resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', parameters('applicationInsightsName'))]",
      "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]",
      "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName'))]"
    ],
    "properties": {
      "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]",
      "siteConfig": {
        "appSettings": [
          {
            "name": "APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING",
            "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', parameters('applicationInsightsName')), '2020-02-02').ConnectionString]"
          },
          {
            "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
            "value": "[format('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={0};EndpointSuffix={1};AccountKey={2}', parameters('storageAccountName'), environment().suffixes.storage, listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName')), '2021-09-01').keys[0].value)]"
          },
          {
            "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING",
            "value": "[format('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={0};EndpointSuffix={1};AccountKey={2}', parameters('storageAccountName'), environment().suffixes.storage, listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName')), '2021-09-01').keys[0].value)]"
          },
          {
            "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE",
            "value": "[toLower(parameters('functionAppName'))]"
          },
          {
            "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
            "value": "~4"
          },
          {
            "name": "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME",
            "value": "dotnet-isolated"
          },
          {
            "name": "WEBSITE_USE_PLACEHOLDER_DOTNETISOLATED",
            "value": "1"
            }
        ],
        "netFrameworkVersion": "[parameters('netFrameworkVersion')]"
      }
    }
  }
]

Please make sure, you have created the related resources like Application Insight, storage account and hosting plan before executing the given script.

This misses the key point that solved my issue which was assigning the setting netFrameworkVersion to v8.0

@MattCook Added in my answer
